# SQL add relations to relation table

Tags: sql, insert

I have 3 tables which manage the users an their rights

```
Employee
+-----------+------+
|EmployeeID | Name |
+-----------+------+
|1          |Tim   |
|2          |Tom   |
+-----------+------+

Right
+-----------+------+
|RightID    |Name  |
+-----------+------+
|1          |Read  |
|2          |Write |
|3          |Change|
+-----------+------+

EmployeeRight
+-----------+--------+
|EmplyeeID  | RightID|
+-----------+--------+
|1          |1       |
|1          |2       |
|2          |1       |
+-----------+--------+
```

Now I need to give all users the right "Change" which have the right "Write". But users that already have that right should not get it twice.

My current attempt does not work:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeRight 
(SELECT '3', EmployeeID FROM EmployeeRight WHERE RightID = 2 AND RightID !=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a single row `RightID` can't be both `2` and `<>2`, you need a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeRight 
SELECT EmployeeID, 3 
FROM EmployeeRight 
WHERE RightID = 2 -- existing right 2
  AND EmployeeID NOT IN
   (
     SELECT EmployeeID 
     FROM EmployeeRight 
     WHERE RightID = 3 -- but not those who already have right 3
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script.

```
INSERT INTO Employee-Right
SELECT EmployeeID,3
FROM Employyee E
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM Employee-Right ER WHERE E.EmployeeID=ER.EmployeeID AND ER.Right=2 )
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM Employee-Right ER WHERE E.EmployeeID=ER.EmployeeID AND ER.Right=3 )
```

OR you can query directly from `Employee-right` table

```
INSERT INTO Employee-Right
SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID,3
FROM Employee-Right ER
WHERE ER.Right=2 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM Employee-Right ER1 WHERE ER.EmployeeID=ER1.EmployeeID AND ER.Right=3 )
```

Comment: thank you +1 for both but that matching by `EmpolyeeID` is a bit more elegant compared to  `SELECT 1`

Comment: NOT IN will not work if the sub query returns NULL value.say if you don't have an employee with RightID = 3 already there in your table Employee-Right,it will return null and your query will fail.

Comment: The `NOT IN` will only fail if there's a row with a NULL EmployeeID returned. As the `EmployeeRight` table is an associative table it should have a Primary Key constraint on the combination `EmplyeeID/RightID` which makes NULLs impossible (otherwise you can still add a `WHERE EmployeeID IS NOT NULL`)

Comment: @dnoeth I agree that the NOT IN will fail only if the subquery returns NULL value and I just wanted to mention that there is a possibility to get a NULL value when processing the subquery in the NOT IN clause(if there is no employee with RightId=3)

Comment: When there's no employee with `RightId=3` the subquery will return no rows, there's no way that it returns a NULL instead.

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
            INSERT INTO EmployeeRight      
            select E.EmployeeID,'3' as RightID from Employee E
            left join EmployeeRight ER on ER.EmplyeeID = E.EmployeeID
            left join Right r on r.RightID=ER.RightID
            where er.RightID = 2 and er.RightID != 3
```